# is the DAG runtime displayed anywhere in the UI?

Tags: airflow

I find it strange that after a run of a DAG completes there is nowhere in the UI to tell me how long it took. Yes, I can go into (say) Graph View or Gannt to see when the first task started and when the last task to end ended, then subtract one from the other but it would be nice if the run duration were simply displayed on the UI somewhere.

Perhaps it *is* displayed on the UI and I'm simply not seeing it. Does anyone know if the duration of a DAG run is displayed in the UI somewhere?

Comment: Not the duration of DAG, but the duration of individual task is displayed on the Browse -> Task Instances page.

Comment: Hi. Yeah, got that thx. Just surprised overall DAG execution time isn't there.